# Gradle srcDirs using kotlin DSL

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

i am trying to convert sourceSets section using kotlin DSL.

In build.gradle I had:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        kotlin { srcDirs = ['src/main/java'] }
        groovy { srcDirs = [] }
    }
    test {
        java { srcDirs = [] }
        groovy { srcDirs = ['src/test/java', 'src/test/groovy'] }
    }
}
```

which after listing shows:

```
MAIN
[$projectPath/dma-core/src/main/java]
[]
TEST
[]
[$projectPath/dma-core/src/test/java, /Users/vondracek/IdeaProjects/DMA/bpp/dma-core/src/test/groovy]
```

if I rewrites it to kotlin DSL with:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        kotlin { srcDirs("src/main/java") }
        groovy { srcDirs.clear() }

        println("main kotlin: ${kotlin.srcDirs}")
        println("main groovy: ${groovy.srcDirs}")
        println("main java: ${java.srcDirs}")
    }
    test {
        java {
            srcDirs.clear()
            //srcDirs(emptyArray<String>())
            //srcDirs(emptyList<String>())
        }

        groovy {
            srcDirs("src/test/java", "src/test/groovy")
        }
        println("test java ${java.srcDirs ?: "empty"}")
        println("test groovy ${groovy.srcDirs}")
    }
}
```

it prints:

```
main kotlin: [$projectPath/dma-core/src/main/kotlin, $projectPath/dma-core/src/main/java]
main groovy: [$projectPath/dma-core/src/main/groovy]
main java: [$projectPath/dma-core/src/main/java]
test java [$projectPath/dma-core/src/test/java]
test groovy [$projectPath/dma-core/src/test/groovy, $projectPath/dma-core/src/test/java]
```

I cant get empty source dirs. As you can see i tried many ways. I also tried to have it in different syntax using named("main") etc.

Any clue why in kotlin DSL the directories are not empty as in groovy DSL?

Comment: Why do you want to clear the groovy srcDirs, if the directories are empty they won't be picked up anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are not doing the same thing, in the groovy code you set it to an empty list, but in kotlin you are calling `.clear()`.

The problem is that [getSrcDirs()](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/fe3503222e2e9916d9ceca44ba9ce9242a4186b6/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/file/DefaultSourceDirectorySet.java#L128-L133) is returning a copy of the actual directories, and changes are not reflected in the internal state, whereas [setSrcDirs(listOf())](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/fe3503222e2e9916d9ceca44ba9ce9242a4186b6/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/file/DefaultSourceDirectorySet.java#L298C31-L302) actually clears the internal state first before adding the given directories.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. "setSrcDirs" is the problem. Yeah next time i will go to docs earlier. Thanks bro.